# Mysql_query in Django's view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a project in Django, this project connects to a mysql database called billing. I'd like to know if can I make a query like:

```
SELECT * from cdr where accountcode = 'MARY'
```

And show the results in a page, my problem is that the database where the table cdr is created  is not the same of my project, it's only in the same server.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

[Documentation on multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/)

[Documentation on raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)